# Stepwise simplification

Tags: replacement

I have a really, *really* complicated set of string simplification rules (only it doesn't actually work on strings, I use stuff like

```
F[x__,a,y__]:=F[x,b,y];
F[x__,b,b,y__]:=F[x,c,y];
```

to get the results on the fly - also I never know beforehand which rule is applicable in a concrete situation). As you can imagine, 100 of these rules have at least one hidden typo.
Is it possible to partially "Hold" the execution with something like this pseudocode happening

```
>exec F[a,a] 3 steps
F[b,a], rule 1 used
F[b,b], rule 1 used
F[c], rule 2 used
Done
>exec F[a,c] 1 steps
F[b,c], rule 1 used
Done
```

so I can then control by hand where a substition went haywire (which is luckily easy)? I.e. print out all intermediate results of the replacements?

Comment: shouldn't `F[x__,a,y__]` be `F[x___,a,y___]`? and similarly,  `F[x__,b,b,y__]` should be `F[x___,b,b,y___]`?

Comment: Correct. I confused the two as in the actual case, rarely something happens at the boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [`Trace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) gives what you need:

```
ClearAll[F]
F[x___, a, y___]:= F[x, b, y];
F[x___, b, b, y___]:= F[x, c, y];

Trace[F[a, a]]
```

> {F[a, a], F[b, a], F[b, b], F[c]}

```
Trace[F[a, c]]
```

> {F[a, c], F[b, c]}

Comment: I should have trusted my intuition which said "Surely, MATHEMATICA has something like a computation trace" and googled myself :-) Anyway, spot on.